# Python tests can't import the module they're testing

Tags: python, import

I know Python imports are a perennial headache, but I can't see why this should be broken:

I have the following file structure:

```
webapp/
    README.md
    ...
    webapp/
        __init__.py
        ...
        tests/
            __init__.py
            test_integration.py
```

webapp/**init**.py is initializing a Flask project, and webapp/tests/test_integration.py is trying to test the homepage.

When I `cd` into `webapp/webapp` and run `python tests/test_integration.py` (which includes the line `import webapp`), I get the error `ImportError: No module named webapp`. I tried `cd`ing up one directory, into the upper `webapp`, as well as down into `tests`, but same deal. I tried adding the absolute path to the inner `webapp` directory to PYTHONPATH, but no avail.

This is strange, since I'm using a similar structure in another project and it seems to be working fine.

Also, if I move `test_integration.py` all the way up into the outer `webapp` directory, it runs just fine. Any reason why the test can't `import webapp` from any further inside the file tree?

Any insight? Thanks!~

Comment: to avoid this issue altogether I usually install the library into the virtual environment, that way I can import from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> "I tried adding the absolute path to the inner webapp directory to PYTHONPATH, but no avail."

You need to add your *outer* `webapp` directory to `PYTHONPATH`.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/webapp:$PYTHONPATH
```

Then your inner `webapp` directory will be visible, and you can import it.